# error C2228: Left of '.begin'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error

```
int result;

result.push_back(digit);
}
int result;
reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
return result;
}
```

When I run my program this section of the code keeps getting the same 2 errors. The errors are:
1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project8\project8\source.cpp(90): error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is 'int'
1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project8\project8\source.cpp(90): error C2228: left of '.end' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is 'int'

I have tried searching to see if anyone else has had this same error, but everyone time I look at the solution and i try to implement it into my own code the error just keeps appearing.

Comment: `int`s don't have any methods... What you need is an introductory book to C++

Comment: If your code _really_  looks like that, and those _aren't_ the only errors you get.  If your code doesn't look _exactly_ like that, how are we to help?

Comment: No that just the section that keeps getting errors.  I have a lot of code but when i get errors they all fall under that section

Comment: You're trying to reverse an `int` by using a method intended for containers using `int`s as iterators?I suggest you read up on `std::reverse` : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Comment: Do you have an `int` called `result` **and** a vector called `result`?

Answer (score 2):

You defined variable result as having type int.

```
int result;
```

Type int has no any methods.

I think you meant something as

```
std::vector<int> result;
```